# Chef Test Kitchen: How to verify Jenkins is running in sandbox

Tags: shell, jenkins, automated-tests, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I am currently using the [Jenkins](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins) Supermarket cookbook to create a Jenkins instance. I am using the [Java_se](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java_se) cookbook to configure Java as a prerequisite of installing Jenkins. Prior to configuring a managed node with the cookbook, I am using Test Kitchen to verify that the provisioning is successful before configuring my managed node.

Once my Test Kitchen instances are up and running, I am verifying the Java installation using the following command:

```
kitchen exec -c 'java -version'
```

which yields the version of Java on the instance if the java configuration has been successful.

My question is, what are some good ways to verify that Jenkins is up and running on the Test Kitchen sandbox instance? I'd like to check the url; for example http://localhost:8080. There are also some additional checks I'd like to do (plugins that are installed as part of the recipe, as well as security that is enabled at the end of configuring the instance).

Does anybody have any good ideas / leads as to how to verify my Jenkins instance is configured correctly when using a Test Kitchen sandbox environment? Thanks everybody for any ideas that may have!

Comment: Here are some additional ideas for verifying Jenkins installed. Uses serverspec: https://github.com/myspotontheweb/chef-jenkins-farm/blob/master/test/integration/master/serverspec/default_spec.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use busser-serverspec, you just write the tests as per normal locally, usually using `Net::HTTP.get('http://localhost:8080/whatever')`.

If you use kitchen-inspec, you need to be a little more roundabout and use something like `describe command('curl http://localhost:8080/whatever')` and work with it like a normal command resource.